# Export impex template page in Hybris

Tags: import, content-management-system, export, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I would copy the mobile pages from the standard electronics b2c site to the mobile pages of my hybris site. How can I do this? With impex or directly in the cmscockpit? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to play around and want to test something the "quick-and-dirty"-way you can use the cms cockpit. (not recommended)

In our project we use only impex files for cms stuff. The main reasons for this approach are:

- your pages and components **do not get lost when you re-initialize the project** with the *ant initialize* command (otherwise they will be deleteted after the initialize)
- you can **version the impex files** in your versioning system and revert changes if necessary
- **single point of maintenace**: you have your pages, components and contentslots all in the same location and do not have to use the cms cockpit to find the since this could be a real pain.
- exporting your pages into impex files is very painful and work intense
- you can **exchage the impex file with others** like partners, contractors etc.

Take care about the location of the impex files since hybris relies heavily on conventions regarding locations and naming. So **make sure that the file is in the correct directory**.

**Hint 1:** You can use the cms cockpit to search and verify the pages you created via impex file.

**Hint 2:** You can execute impex Statements directly in the hybris administration console (hac). Your changes are of immediate effect and you do not have to initialize the system after changing the content of the impex file. *This will save you a lot of time*.

Navigate to hac -> Console -> ImpEx Import and paste your impex statemts into the textarea. Do not forget to paste also the variable declarations.

If they are correct copy them to the impex file and save it to persist your work.

Comment: Thanks @dakillerbee! This is the approach i would use, just because I don't want lose the work every 30 days. 
My question is: what impex files I have to create to obtain the right layout for the mobile pages? Can I copy some impex files from the standard accelerator? Help me please

Comment: @shakbait: Unfortunately I am not familiar with the electronics store. But the **cms-mobile-content.impex** and the **cms-content.impex** files might be a good starting point.

Comment: What I forgot to mention: the impex-files might be located in an project which might end in "initialdata". It should have directory ..\resources\<projectname>\import\. This is hybris convention for the impex import directories. 

The java class **InitialDataSystemSetup.java** might also be useful because there are all impex-files and paths listed which are used during the initialization. Just make sure to get the right one because there can be more thamn one. ;-)